# Cassandra performance issues with GC

Tags: cassandra

We are currently having minor timeouts in the Cassandra and I came across longer "stop-the-world" times in the GC log on 5 of 8 nodes while searching for the problem:

```
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 2.4754046 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001525 seconds
```

I then visualised the gc logs to get a better picture and for 5 of the 8 nodes they all look something like this:

[image: Node1]

In contrast, the 3 other nodes in the cluster:
[image]

In contrast to the first 5 nodes, the "stop-the-world" times are always in the 200ms range.

A little more context on the nodes themselves:
All nodes run the same Cassandra version 3.11.5 and the Cassandra config + jvm settings are the same everywhere. The first 5 nodes also differ hardware-wise in CPU and hard drives. Node 1 to Node 5 have 32 CPU cores and slow spinning disks. Node 6 to Node 8 have 16 cores and fast NVME SSDs for commitlog and SSTables.

The nodes have 128 GB of memory and the heap size is set to 64 GB. The garbage collector is G1.

Why does the garbage collector on the first 5 nodes behave so differently to the other nodes in terms of "stop the world" times?

Thanks and Cheers!

Edit:
I checked some Dashboards and found out that the 5 nodes with this problem have a hughe amount of major pagefaults for the java process (~4k major page faults).

Where do they come from? And why are they only on these 5 nodes? Could it be because they are NUMA systems and Cassandra is having problems with them?